# How to build SPA using sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, single-page-application, client-side

My company is big on sharepoint. but server side controls have inherent problem with performance. I want to move page rendering responsibility to client side with concept similar to SPA. what is best framework or architectural style for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single Page Applications are gaining immense popularity these days mainly because of their fluidity and responsiveness. Clearly the framework and architectural style depends heavily upon the requirements.
**Framework:-**
There are host of frameworks available that can be leveraged depending upon the complexity of the SPA you are planning - Backbone, Angular, Knockout, Ember etc. I personally prefer Angular and Knockout frameworks because of their simplicity and data binding and directive capabilities. Moreover you can also efficiently handle REST calls to SharePoint using Breeze.js. Refer to [this](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/breezejs-makes-client-side-sharepoint-2013-rest-development-a-breeze) link for more details.
**Architecture Styles:-**
Typically SPAs use MVC or MVVM patterns to decouple the UI aspect from the business logic, but this again is requirement driven. Regardless of the style/pattern it is important to keep the code modular and no to expose implementation details as much as possible.
**Packaging:-**
As far as SPAs for SharePoint are concerned, the best way to package and deploy them is in the form of SharePoint Hosted Apps. SharePoint Hosted Apps only allow client side code and hence leveraging Javascript object model and REST API for SharePoint making them ideal for deployment of SPA over SharePoint.
**References:-**
https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/building-sharepoint-apps-spa-angularjs